# Split grouped data set into packages that should not exceed a maximum size

Tags: r

For further processing I need to divide my data into chunks that should not exceed a certain size of rows, with the condition, that cases belonging to the same group should not divided into different chunks, and that the group sizes are varying.

So let's say i have table like this:

```
df <- tibble(id = c("id1", "id1", "id2", "id2", "id2", "id3", "id4", "id5", "id5", "id6"),
             group_size = c(2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1))

   id    group_size
   <chr>      <dbl>
 1 id1            2
 2 id1            2
 3 id2            3
 4 id2            3
 5 id2            3
 6 id3            1
 7 id4            1
 8 id5            2
 9 id5            2
10 id6            1
```

In case the chunk size should not be bigger than 3. Then the variable indicating which case belongs into which split part should look like this:

```
   id    group_size  part
   <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 id1            2     1
 2 id1            2     1
 3 id2            3     2
 4 id2            3     2
 5 id2            3     2
 6 id3            1     3
 7 id4            1     3
 8 id5            2     4
 9 id5            2     4
10 id6            1     4
```

Is there already a function or package that could do this job and if not, how could this be programmed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a function that does this task, so far, so I solved it by the following steps:

1. Count the group sizes cumulativly.
2. If the cumulative count with the new group exceeds the given chunk size, start a new chunk and begin new counting.

```
       id    group_size cum_size  part
       <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
     1 id1            2        2     1
     2 id1            2        2     1
     3 id2            3        3     2
     4 id2            3        3     2
     5 id2            3        3     2
     6 id3            1        1     3
     7 id4            1        2     3
     8 id5            2        2     4
     9 id5            2        2     4
    10 id6            1        3     4
```

As usual there are many ways to do it in R. One way could simply be a for loop over the cases.

```r
df$part <- 1 # start with part 1
cum_size <- df$group_size[1] # init with size of first group
max_chunk_size <- 3

for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if (df$id[i] == df$id[i-1]) { # if id is the same as previus row, copy part value 
    df$part[i] <- df$part[i-1]
    print(cum_size)
  }
  else if (cum_size + df$group_size[i] <= max_chunk_size) { # else if the next group fits in the chunk, copy part value
    cum_size <- cum_size + df$group_size[i]
    df$part[i] <- df$part[i-1]
  }
  else { # start a new part, and begin group size counting a new.
    cum_size <- df$group_size[i]
    df$part[i] <- df$part[i-1] + 1
    print(cum_size)
  }
}
```

Another way follows the same approach but instead of a for loop this time I use the accumulate function from the purrr package. In this approach I also iterate over the row numbers. However, this solution fit's well into a tidyverse `%>%` command chain.

```r
max_chunk_size <- 3

df %>%
  mutate(
    cum_size = accumulate(
      .x = row_number()[-1],
      .f = function(lag_cum_size, i) {
        if (id[i] == id[i-1]) lag_cum_size # if id is same as previous id copy cum_size value
        else if (lag_cum_size + group_size[i] <= max_chunk_size) lag_cum_size + group_size[i] # else if new group fits into chunk, add its group size to cum size. 
        else (group_size[i]) # else start new cum_size counting with current group size. 
      },
      .init = group_size[1]), # init with first value of group_size
    part = cumsum(if_else(id == lag(id) | lag(group_size) + cum_size <= max_chunk_size, 0, 1, 1)))
```